# Let $G$ be a finite group, $ord(G)=p^2$ ($p$ is a prime) prove that there is a subgroup of order $p$ in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $ord(G)=p^2$ ($p$ is a prime) prove that there is a subgroup of order $p$ in $G$

I thout about Sylow theorem but it didn't helped me.

Comment: did you see Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: We didn't lernt yet Cauchy theorem

Comment: If you did not learn Cauchy's theorem yet, how come you are attempting to use Sylow???

Comment: We didn't learn Sylow either, I read about It by myself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an approach that doesn't use Cauchy's Theorem. An element of order $p$ generates a subgroup of order $p$, so we need to find some $x\in G$ with $|x|=p$.

Let $x\in G$ be a non-identity element. By Lagrange's Theorem, order of $x$ divides $p^2$, so $|x|=1, p$ or $p^2$. Since $x$ is not the identity element, $|x|=p$ or $|x|=p^2$. If $|x|=p$, we win. If $|x|=p^2$, then the element $y=x^{p}$ has order $p$.

Comment: Very nice solution +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this particular problem very elementarily, without even invoking Cauchy's theorem, let alone Sylow's. Hints:

1) Every non-trivial subgroup of $G$ has order $p$ or $p^2$.

2) Suppose $G$ had no subgroup of order $p$. Pick any $g\ne e$ in $G$. Let $H=\langle g \rangle$ be the generated subgroup.

3) Argue that $|H|=p^2$, and thus $G=H$.

4) But then $G$ is cyclic, so it is isomorphic to.... and in that group you can easily find an element of order $p$. Contradiction.